# Spring boot + jpa +mysql error on aws or openshift

Tags: java, hibernate, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, openshift-3

I tried to deploy my application on AWS and Openshift, the applications seems to work fine until I try to access GET `/users` endpoint after a POST (saved user without company data). 

It returns:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not prepare statement; SQL [select companies0_.users_id as users_id1_8_0_, companies0_.companies_id as companie2_8_0_, company1_.id as id1_0_1_, company1_.contact_id as contact_4_0_1_, company1_.gallery_id as gallery_5_0_1_, company1_.active as active2_0_1_, company1_.promoted as promoted3_0_1_, company1_.location_id as location6_0_1_, company1_.profile_id as profile_7_0_1_, company1_.subscription_id as subscrip8_0_1_, contact2_.id as id1_1_2_, contact2_.email as email2_1_2_, contact2_.phone as phone3_1_2_, gallery3_.id as id1_2_3_, location4_.id as id1_3_4_, location4_.address as address2_3_4_, location4_.city as city3_3_4_, location4_.country as country4_3_4_, location4_.country_code as country_5_3_4_, location4_.latitude as latitude6_3_4_, location4_.longitude as longitud7_3_4_, profile5_.id as id1_5_5_, profile5_.company_category as company_2_5_5_, profile5_.creation_date as creation3_5_5_, profile5_.description as descript4_5_5_, profile5_.name as name5_5_5_, profile5_.thumbnail as thumbnai6_5_5_, subscripti6_.id as id1_6_6_, subscripti6_.subscription_end_date as subscrip2_6_6_, subscripti6_.subscription_start_date as subscrip3_6_6_ from users_companies companies0_ inner join companies company1_ on companies0_.companies_id=company1_.id left outer join contacts contact2_ on company1_.contact_id=contact2_.id left outer join gallery gallery3_ on company1_.gallery_id=gallery3_.id left outer join locations location4_ on company1_.location_id=location4_.id left outer join profiles profile5_ on company1_.profile_id=profile5_.id left outer join subscription subscripti6_ on company1_.subscription_id=subscripti6_.id where companies0_.users_id=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

The logs are as follows:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException:could not prepare statement
```

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:user lacks privilege or object not found:COMPANIES in statement
```

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException:user lacks privilege or object not found:COMPANIES
```

But all these works perfectly fine on local server with mysql.

The controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

     @Autowired
     UserRepository repository;

    @GetMapping(value = "/users", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
     public ResponseEntity getUsers() {
     return new ResponseEntity<>(repository.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {
}
```

User model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@DynamicUpdate
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    @SerializedName("id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, updatable = false)
    @SerializedName("email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @SerializedName("password")
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "accessToken")
    @SerializedName("accessToken")
    private String accessToken;

    @Column(name = "phoneNumber")
    @SerializedName("phoneNumber")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "createdAt", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @SerializedName("createdAt")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updatedAt", nullable = false)
    @SerializedName("updatedAt")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedAt;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Company> companies;

    //getters & setters etc
}
```

Company model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "companies")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    @SerializedName("id")
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @SerializedName("profile")
    private Profile profile;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @SerializedName("contact")
    private Contact contact;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @SerializedName("location")
    private Location location;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @SerializedName("gallery")
    private Gallery gallery;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @SerializedName("subscription")
    private Subscription subscription;

    @Column(name = "active", columnDefinition = "tinyint(1) default 0")
    @SerializedName("active")
    private boolean isActive;

    @Column(name = "promoted", columnDefinition = "tinyint(1) default 0")
    @SerializedName("promoted")
    private boolean isPromoted;

    //getters & setters etc
}
```

Application properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://host:3306/database
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

Any idea what cause this problem? Also I mentioned above this works perfectly fine on local machine.

**UPDATE** Its seems if I don't provide data for every object in relations when saving (exp.User/Company,Company/Profile,Company/Contact etc) a user to db it gives this error.

Comment: ```user lacks privilege or object not found``` can have multiple causes, the most obvious being you're accessing a table that does not exist. Can you plz very companies table in prod env database

Comment: I checked but for some reason the database accessed remotely does not reflect the data/changes on the server.So I can't tell whats the problem...